# Rails collection_select modify output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In one of the views (erb) I have the following code

```
collection_select(:wp_article, :wp_site_id, WpSite.find_by_sql(["SELECT wp_sites.* FROM wp_sites, users_wp_sites, users WHERE users_wp_sites.user_id = users.id and users_wp_sites.wp_site_id = wp_sites.id and username= ?", session[:cur_username]]), :id, :name, 

{:prompt => true})
```

This lists the site names that are accessible by the current user (cur_username) in a drop down list, for example

```
Google.com
Facebook.com
Twitter.com
```

Now I need to display the number of times that the user has accessed these sites in the same drop down list, like this:

```
Google.com (32)
Facebook.com (68)
Twitter.com (21)
```

How can I modify the query to include the count together with the site name?
(I know how to get the count in a subquery within the same query posted above, but do not know how to pass name of site (:name) and count (the new count I will get in the subquery) to the drop down list as one complete string.)

Comment: Why don't you just use Activerecord, and then you can make a call like  `acessible_sites.each { |site| puts "#{site.name} (#{site.visits})` or something to that affect.  This find_by_sql line is ugly and doesn't seem like it takes advantage of rails or adheres to the rails way.

Comment: @Batkins The counts ("number of times that the user has accessed these sites") varies continually, so I have to get them dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it in this way:

```
<%= collection_select(:wp_article, :wp_site_id, WpSite.find_by_sql(["SELECT wp_sites.id, CONCAT(wp_sites.name, ' (', (select count(*) from wp_articles where wp_articles.wp_site_id = wp_sites.id and wp_articles.author = users.username and published = 1), ')') name FROM wp_sites, users_wp_sites, users WHERE users_wp_sites.user_id = users.id and users_wp_sites.wp_site_id = wp_sites.id and username= ?", session[:cur_username]]), :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
```

In the main SQL query I am using CONCAT (it is a MySQL backend) to append the count to the name and keeping the attribute name "name" (so that it is referenced by symbol :name).